# is there a better way to size divs than trial and error?

Tags: html, css, sizing

I seem to spend a lot of time fiddling with the sizes of divs. I put in a rough guess and then have to fine-tune it till it's right. It takes ages.

I'm manually changing the width/height and margins.

Is there a better way? Or will I just get my eye in with practice?

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for design-wise exactly but what I recommend to you is to look into [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for example which would probably make your life easier. However, I don't recommend asking opinion-based questions like this as you will most likely end up with negative question points. Every developer might give you a different answer on this one..

Comment: thanks. I don't really want to use bootstrap. I was just looking for a quicker way to do it. What i'm using now is a chrome extension which allows me to measure things. I probably should have made clear I'm woriking through the odin course, which asks you to recreate pages such as youtube.

I am a bit confused as to why this is considered opinion-based but i suppose it's preference how you do it. thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative sizes like in `%` and you can always use devTool of the browser to get the sizes right rather than going back and forth with the code. [Here's](http://www.arulerforwindows.com/index.html) an app that can help you know what size is what in advance

Comment: thank you! I'm on a mac so i can't use the ruler app but i'll use relative sizing and the dev tool